# Bundle returns NULL

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, null, bundle

I have my data carried forward from Activity to Fragment. However, i do not manage to retrieve the data from bundle with `getArguments()`.

Here is my code of Drawer Activity:

```
case R.id.nav_home:
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
            // set Fragmentclass Arguments
            HomePageFragment homePageFragment = new HomePageFragment();
            homePageFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, homePageFragment).commit();
            break;
```

Here is my code for Home Fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    String strtext = bundle.getString("edttext");
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_google_map, container, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try retrieving it in onViewCreated(...)?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit code of Activity** -

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
      final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
      final MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();

 Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("message", editText.getText().toString());
            myFragment.setArguments(b);
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frameLayout, myFragment).commit();
```

**Edit Home Fragment** -

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
      String message = bundle.getString("message");
      textView.setText(message);
```